# Обработка Ajax запроса сервером NodeJS

Tags: ajax, node.js, веб-программирование

Как обработать Ajax запрос на сервере:

html+script:

```
    <div id = "divTXT">
    Сюда подгрузятся данные TXT
    </div>
    <button id = "buttonGetData">Получить данные </button>

    <script>

    var buttonGetData = document.getElementById('buttonGetData');
    buttonGetData.addEventListener('click', ShowData);

    function ShowData(event)
    {
        event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
        url: "/server.js",
        response:'text',
        success: function(receive){
            $("#divTXT").append(receive);
        }
    });

    </script>
```

Сервер:

```
      var http = require("http");
      var url = require("url");
      var mysql = require('mysql');
      var fs  = require('fs');
      formidable = require('formidable');

    function onServer(route, newServer, reqtype) {

    function onRequest(request, response){
    var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
    try {pathname = pathname.substring(1, pathname.length);} catch (err){}
     if (request.method === 'POST')
            post(request, response, pathname);
    else{
        if (pathname !== "favicon.ico") {
            openPage(response, pathname);
        }
    }
   }

   function openPage(response, pathname){
        var path = route(pathname);
        var html = "";
        html = newServer(path);
        var type = reqtype(path);
        response.writeHead(302, {"Content-Type" : "text/" + type});
        response.write(html);
        response.end();
     }

    function post(request, response, pathname){
    switch(pathname){
    case "registration.html":
        var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
            form.parse(request, function(err, params, files){

                fs.appendFile('txt/user.txt', params["login"]);
                fs.appendFile('txt/user.txt', params["sPass"]);
                openPage(response, "successfulRegistration.html");
        });
            break;
        case "autorization.html":
            var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
            form.parse(request, function(err, params, files){
                connection.query('SELECT * from loginsandpasswords',  params, function(err, rows, fields){
                    if (!err){
                        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){
                            if (rows[i].login === params.login && rows[i].password === params.password){
                                console.log('5');
                                console.log('authorization');
                                openPage(response, "home.html");
                                return 0;
                            }
                        }
                        console.log(params);
                    }
                });
            });
            break;
        case "messages.html":
            var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
            form.parse(request, function(err, params, files){
                if (!err) {
                    console.log(params);
                    connection.query("INSERT INTO messages VALUES (?,?,?,?)", [params["name"], params["email"], params["subject"], params["comment"]], function (err, result) {
                        if (!err)
                            console.log('comment has been add');
                        else
                            console.log(err.message);
                    });
                }
                else  console.log(err.message);
            });
            break;
        case "mentions.html":
            var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
            form.parse(request, function(err, params, files){
                if (!err) {
                    console.log(params);
                    connection.query("INSERT INTO mentions VALUES (?,?)", [params["name"],  params["comment"]], function (err, result) {
                        if (!err)
                            console.log('comment has been add');

                        else
                            console.log(err.message);
                    });

                }
                else  console.log(err.message);
            });
            break;
      default: console.log("Uncorrect choice");
     }
}
http.createServer(onRequest).listen(5656);
console.log("Server started on port 5656");


 };

exports.onServer = onServer;
```

Comment: для начала создать сервер.. или его тоже надо написать?

Comment: @C.Raf.T, сервер создан, интересует подход обработки запросов

Comment: так покажите серверную часть...

Comment: @C.Raf.T, нужно обработать запрос - отправив данные из .txt документа на сервере, реализация?

Comment: @C.Raf.T, показал, а ответа нет(

Comment: прошу прощение, вчера не успел..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

можно вот так:

```
function foo(path) {  
    fs.readFile(path, 'utf8', (err, data)=>{
        if(err){
            // exception
            console.log(err)
        }else{
            console.log(data)
            // data текст в фаиле. оборачиваете его во что хотите и вперед.   
            //(пример: request.JSON(data)) 
        }     
    })  
}
```